# Login fail in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, basic-authentication

I'm Laravel Beginner

I make some web application using laravel 4.2 then I make login page but when I try to login it's go to login fail condition every time

anyone tell why

here is my code

```
public function doLogIn(){

        $rules = array(
            'username'    => 'required|min:3', 
            'password' => 'required|min:3'
        );

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return 'Wrong Require';
        }
        else{

            $user = array(
                'username' => Input::get('username'),
                'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'))
            );

            $password = Hash::make('password');

            if (Auth::attempt($user)) 
            {
                return View::make('home.home');
            }
            else
            {
                return 'Wrong Password';
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$user = array(
    'username' => Input::get('username'),
    'password' => Input::get('password')
);
```

You must remove `Hash::make()` in `Auth::attempt()`, because Laravel makes hashing automatically (I suppose that you register user with `Hash::make(Input::get('password'))`).